# getting result from a specific base in a templated class with variable number of templated arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-template

I am trying to implement a templated class like below.

```
   struct Ciccio2 : public T1, public T2, public T3, public T4
   {
     template<typename TR>
     int get(const string& s) const
     {
       return TR::operator()(s);
     }
   };
```

All templated argument are like the following sample class

```
   struct AA{ 
     int operator()(const string& s) { return 1;}
   };
```

I am trying also to have a global extractor function but when I use the template function below g++ gives me a build error saying

```
   template<class TA, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
   int extract(const Ciccio2<T1,T2,T3,T4>& obj, const string& s)
   {
     return obj.get<TA>(s);
   }
```

the code below doesn't buld saying

```
expected primary expression before > token
```

Is it correct what I am trying to implement?

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: (unrelated to your question, the path of multiple inheritance only leads to madness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `obj` is a type-dependent expression, the compiler won't use name lookup to determine whether `obj.get` is an object, function, type, or template.  Unless you force it to do otherwise, the compiler assumes it is an object or function for syntax analysis.  Next it sees the `<` less than operator (not the `<` beginning a template argument list), and soon afterward gets confused.  You need:

```
return obj.template get<TA>(s);
```

See also the question [Where and why do I have to put the template and typename keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Wow..first time I see this usage of tempate word. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `TR` is one of `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, and `T4`, the line:

```
   return TR::operator()(s);
```

should be:

```
   return TR().operator()(s);
```

or

```
   return TR()(s);
```

Since `operator()` cannot be a static member function.

Comment: But if `TR::operator()` is a member of `*this`, it can be valid with the implicit `this->`.  (At least, I think it's valid without the explicit `this->`...)